# chat,js stacked bar chart (make one dataset into stacked)

Tags: chart.js

Trying to put one dataset into stacked on bar chart .. is it possible ?? please refer my fiddle link [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gayathrig321/9xrb0vhe/4310/), 
Just want to make `test 3` data into stacked one.
my datasets are passed like this `

```
var dataSet = '';
var datasets = [];
for (i in label) {
  dataSet = {
    label: label[i],
    data: dataY[i]
  };
 datasets.push(dataSet);
}
var barData = {
 labels: dataX,
 datasets: datasets
};
```

`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As far as I searched google It seems it is not possible to put stacked grouped graph using chart.js and solution is to use D3.js

Comment: Its not possible to stack data in grouped chart...[link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5377)

Comment: So you've created an unclear question to which you seem to already have known the answer (as you've linked the same image from that github link), which already has a question on SO?

Comment: No now only found this

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the [`stacked` option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) on both the x and y axes:

```js
var stackedBar = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [1,2,3],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'series1',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        data: [1,2,1],
        stack: 1
      },{
        label: 'series2',
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
        data: [1,2,2],
        stack: 2
      },{
        label: 'series3',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
        data: [2,1,2],
        stack: 2
      }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for your response..but I need graph like this [link] (https://communities.sas.com/legacyfs/online/6479_stacked%20bar%20with%20column%20grouping.png)